# Comparison of web widgets in flash and javascript

Tags: javascript, flash, widget

I want to create a photo browser web widget that can be embedded in a web page (e.g alice's blog) but I am not sure whether I should go the flash or javascript route.

Flickr went with a flash based widget. Why would they do it in flash over javascript?

And conversely, why would you chose js based widget over flash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Flash

**Pros**

1. Better suited for animations and such.
2. No stupid issues like IE 6 png or CSS issues

**Cons**

1. Bad for SEO and usability. Of course you can include everything that is in the Flash as HTML in the page, and read them from Flash.
2. Apple resists it.

   ...

### Javascript

**Pros**

1. Less obtrusive and more SEO-friendly.
2. You don't need to know Flash.

**Cons**

1. Generally you can only achieve a small set of animations and effects that would be possible in Flash.
2. You should check your CSS, HTML, and if you plan to support IE 6 (there are still an unnegligible number of users using it), transparent png's.

Comment: AJAX isn't that more SEO friendly.. Another point would be that Flash can implement some security features; I guess that might be important for Flickr based on how they generally make different images not available to everybody (especially in other sizes).

Comment: Photo browser widgets generally use AJAX less often, and you can easily give a link to (a real) page 2, this can't easily be done in Flash. As for security, I don't think it does matter whether it's Flash or Javascript, as long as it's client-based. In fact, since Flash has access to more internal resources, horrible things can happen. Remember that notorious webcam vuln. that  was silently affecting each of us till the ver. 10.

Comment: don't you have to write the markup in javascript (e.g: document.write("<insert your html>"))? so that makes it useless for SEO. and more importantly it can be pretty painful for a non trivial widget

Comment: Certainly no. Any modern Javascript widget will (and does) use the HTML that is already there. I.e. you build your pages as if they are completely static and have link based navigation, attach Js outside HTML. From here, if the users have their Javascript enabled, Js will take over and do everything needed. If they don't have Js support, they navigate normally. No user or search engine is harmed.

Comment: Well, it's about js dev in general. Look at the source code of great widgets, with preferably good source code too. Examples: [jQuery plugin authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring), SO question on [writing javascript widgets] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899812/best-practices-for-writing-javascript-widgets), ... (there was a question asking about jquery widget tutorials)