# Creating an embeddable javascript widget that uses other js libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, widget

**Objective**

I am trying to build a widget that puts a floating button on my users' sites. On click the button, I would show a web form (that sits on my server) in the form of a lightbox - I am currently using [Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/).

**Problem**

In this case my widget relies on two dependent libraries, `jQuery` and `Fancybox`. How can I ensure that they are both loaded before I call my fancybox codes to load my URL? I have tried looking at few SO questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899812/best-practices-for-writing-javascript-widgets), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170439/how-to-embed-javascript-widget-that-depends-on-jquery-into-an-unknown-environmen), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411501/creating-a-javascript-widget-for-other-sites) and some others) and also [Alex Marandon's great tutorial](http://alexmarandon.com/articles/web_widget_jquery/) but they don't seem to rely on another library such as in my case fancybox.

I did something like the below but my main problem was with the Fancybox libraries being loaded asynchronously using `$.getScript` and hence not available for calling when I called for them few lines after.

```
/******** Our main function ********/
function main() {
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
  /******* Load FANCYBOX *******/
  var fancy_link = $("<link>", { 
    rel: "stylesheet", 
    type: "text/css", 
    href: widgetURL + "fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5",
    media: "screen"
  });
  fancy_link.appendTo('head');
  var fancy2_link = $("<link>", { 
    rel: "stylesheet", 
    type: "text/css", 
    href: widgetURL + "fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7",
    media: "screen"
  });
  fancy2_link.appendTo('head');

  var fancyboxScript = widgetURL + "fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5";
  $.getScript(fancyboxScript);

  var fancyboxScript2 = widgetURL + "fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7";
  $.getScript(fancyboxScript2);

  /******* Load CSS *******/
  var css_link = $("<link>", { 
    rel: "stylesheet", 
    type: "text/css", 
    href: widgetURL + "myWidget.css" 
  });
  css_link.appendTo('head');

  /******* Load Javascript *******/   

  var widgetJS = widgetURL + "widgetFunction.js";
  $.getScript(widgetJS); 

  /******* Load HTML *******/
  var jsonp_url = widgetURL + "myWidgetCall.php?callback=?";

  $.getJSON(jsonp_url,params, function(data) {
    $('#widget-container').html(data.html);
  });
});
}
```

I am no expert in this field, so if there are other alternative methods to achieve the same objective stated above, I will be happy to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$.getScript has a callback success function:

```
jQuery.getScript( url [, success(script, textStatus, jqXHR) ] )
```

So, you can make it as follows:

```
$.getScript(fancyboxScript, function(script, textStatus, jqXHR){ 
      "call your methods here";
});
```

Comment: thanks for your response. so in my case if one of my scripts depend on another to load I should nest them all into their own callback function? like callback function { $.getScript(fancyboxScript2, function(...) { $.getScript(widgetJS, function(...) { /** LOAD HTML **/

Comment: yes, you could try to better structure your code for more legibility and so, but basically yes you have to wait for scripts to be load and so wait for the succes callbacks functions to be called.

Comment: you can also give a try to requireJS.